# Seg Fault and Pointer issues

Tags: c++, linux

Been working on this program for a couple of days in class and I keep getting seg faults. I can comment out the part of code that I think is causing it and I stop getting the fault but then my print function doesn't work. I am picking up the c++ book tomorrow to help.

```
//linkedList.cpp
//Declaration of main and menu functions
//Programmer: Ronnie Warden
//Date: 2.15.15

#include<iostream>
#include "link.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Node *list = new Node;
    int delNode;
    int findNode;
    int choice = 1;
    list->next = NULL;

    while (choice != 5)
    {
        choice = menu();

        if (choice == 1)
            *list = insertNode(list);

        if (choice == 2)
        {   
            cout << "Enter the ID you wish to delete: ";
            cin >> delNode;
            *list = deleteNode(list, delNode);
        }

        if (choice == 3)
            printNode(list);

        if (choice == 4)
        {
            cout << "Enter the ID you are searching for: ";
            cin >> findNode;
            *list = searchNode(list, findNode);
        }

    if (choice < 1 || choice > 5)
        cout << "Invalid choice! Please try again." << endl;

}

return 0;
}

int menu()
{
    int choice = 1;

         cout << "1. Insert Node" << endl;
         cout << "2. Delete Node" << endl;
         cout << "3. Print List" << endl;
         cout << "4. Search List" << endl;
         cout << "5. Quit" << endl;
         cin >> choice;

return choice;
}
```

This following part is the one throwing the seg fault.

```
//linkFun.cpp
//Declaration of functions used to manage the linked list
//Programmer: Ronnie Warden
//Date: 2.10.15

#include<iostream>
#include "link.h"
using namespace std;


/*************************************************************************************************************
Function: createNode
Parameters: No parameters
Return Type: Pointer to new node
Task: Create a node with "new" operator. Get a student data from keyboard and assign to members of the node.
*************************************************************************************************************/

Node createNode()
{
Node *newNode = new Node;

    cout << "Last Name?" << endl;
    cin >> newNode->lastName;
    cout << "First Name?" << endl;
    cin >> newNode->firstName;
    cout << "ID?" << endl;
    cin >> newNode->idNumber;

return *newNode;
}

/**************************************************************************************************************
Function: insertNode
Parameters: Pointer to the linked list
Return Type: Pointer to the linked list
Task: insert a new node to the linked list sorted by student's ID number. If ID is already in list notify user 
***************************************************************************************************************/

Node insertNode(Node *list)
{
    Node *newNode = new Node;
    Node *tmp = new Node;
    *newNode = createNode();
    int id = newNode->idNumber;

    if (list == NULL)           //Insert in empty list
        list->next = newNode;
    else
    {
         *tmp = searchNode(list, id);

         if (tmp->idNumber == newNode->idNumber)
             {
                cout << "ID number already in list! Please try again with a different ID number." << endl;
                insertNode(list);
        }

    if (list != NULL)
    {
        Node *tmp = list;

         if (tmp->idNumber > newNode->idNumber)     //Insert as first
         {
             newNode->next = tmp;
            list = newNode;
        }
    while (tmp->idNumber < newNode->idNumber)   //Search for insertion point
    {   
                if (tmp->next == NULL)        //Insert at end
                            tmp->next == newNode;

        tmp = tmp->next;

        if (tmp->idNumber < newNode->idNumber && tmp->next->idNumber > newNode->idNumber && tmp->next != NULL)  //Insert in-between
        {
            newNode->next = tmp->next->next;
            tmp->next = newNode;
        }

        }
    }
}
return *list;
}

 /***************************************************************************************************************
Function: searchNode
Parameters: Pointer to the linked list, student ID number
Return Type: Pointer to the node with matched ID number
Task: Search the linked list by student Id number. Notify user if ID is not found
***************************************************************************************************************/

Node searchNode(Node *list, int id)
{
    Node *missing = new Node;

    if (list->idNumber == id)   //Checks if first node matches id number
         return *list;
    else 
    {
        Node *tmp = new Node;   //creates temporary pointer to scroll through list
        while (tmp->idNumber != id)
       {    
            if (tmp->next == NULL)  //checks if number is missing returns sentinel if not found
            {
                missing->idNumber = 9999;   
                return *missing;
            }

             tmp = tmp->next;
         }
     return *tmp;

     }
 }

/***************************************************************************************************************
Function: deleteNode
Parameters: Pointer to the linked list, student ID number
Return Type: Pointer to the list
Task: Delete a node from the list. Notify user if no node matches
***************************************************************************************************************/

Node deleteNode(Node *list, int id)
{   
    Node *tmp = new Node;
    *tmp = searchNode(list, id);    
return *list;

}

/***************************************************************************************************************
Function: printNode
Parameters: Pointer to the linked list
Return Type: None
Task: Display the linked list
***************************************************************************************************************/

void printNode(Node *list)
{
    Node *tmp = new Node;
    tmp = list;

    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        cout << tmp->lastName << endl;
        cout << tmp->firstName << endl;
        cout << tmp->idNumber << endl;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}
```

If I comment out the entire else statement in the insertNode function I stop getting the seg fault but then when I call to print it prints 3 blank lines and then 0. Any help would be appreciated, and if it comes up, the reason I didnt use classes was because I am not allowed to, it has to be done in structured data type.

```
#ifndef LINK_H
#define LINK_H

struct Node {
    char lastName[20];
    char firstName[20];
    int idNumber;
    Node *next;
};

int menu();
Node createNode();
Node insertNode(Node*);
Node searchNode(Node*, int);
Node deleteNode(Node*, int);
void printNode(Node*);

#endif
```

Comment: All of my programming is done in terminal on linux

Comment: `I can comment out the part of code that I think is causing it and I stop getting the fault but then my print function doesn't work.`  Well, you're supposed to fix the parts of the code that do not work properly, not just go on as if there is no harm done.

Comment: `if (list == NULL)  list->next = newNode;` Now there's some quality coding right there!

Comment: @Ronnie - if you can't see the problem with the line I posted than you're in over your head.

Comment: @Ronnie What good is a "running" program when you've cut out probably something that must work correctly for the rest of your program to work correctly?  You don't write programs this way.

Comment: Won't compile. `menu()` has no prototype. This is C++, right ? And what are things like `*tmp->lastName` supposed to be doing? There appear to be a multitude of places where `*tmp` is used when `tmp` should be present instead.

Comment: @John3136 completely went over my head. I see that now, I probably should have bought and read the book before posting

Comment: @WhozCraig the `*tmp->lastName` in the print function was a typo. The class Im in isnt taught very well and I havent the slightest clue what Im doing along with the majority of my peers. And the prototypes are in the header file which I did not include

Comment: Yeah, you need a good book and/or a better class, Things like `Node *tmp = new Node;   tmp = list;` literally leak memory in two short lines. This code is *smattered* with logic defects. Most of this looks like C code that someone throw some C++ at and hoped it would stick. Sorry for the dreadful class.

Comment: Show your definition of Node and then check that the name fields are actually backed by storage (either an array or a pointer with an allocation statement).

Comment: @DrC added the header file to the question

Comment: @WhozCraig the class was originally suppose to be C but apparently it changed to C++ and doesnt make sense because its all mashed up together. This is the first of the weekly labs

Comment: @Ronnie The fiends. They're fundamentally *different*. A C class is supposed to be about C, a C++ class for C++. Especially since the adoption of C++11, there are *fundamental* concrete differences in programming ideologies. Damn dude, that sucks.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie if you get a minute could you email me. emails in my bio

Comment: @John3136 ^^ you too ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that you're not using pointers right - you're kind of half way between pointers and objects. (I'm not going to address the fact that this is a C style program in C++)

For example: Your `createNode()` method returns a `Node` object. It does this by creating a new `Node` on the heap and then returning that node's contents. This means that you've actually got a memory leak. No one has remembered the pointer to the node you put in the heap and so it leaks.

My first step would be to make `createNode()` return a `Node*`

```
Node* createNode()
{
    Node *newNode = new Node;

    // All your cout/cin stuff

    return newNode;
}
```

I'd follow the same pattern with the other methods - use pointers rather than objects. Take `searchNode()` as an example. Because you're using objects, you need a special "Not Found" node. If you use pointers, you can return NULL (preferable 0 in C++) for the "not found case". You also don't need to `new` and temporary variables.

```
Node* searchNode(Node* list, int id)
{
    while(list != 0) {
        if (list->id == id) {
            return list;
        }
        // This only impacts the local list. It doesn't
        // permanently change the value of the list
        // passed in.
        list = list->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For bonus points on `searchNode()`: Since it is a sorted list, you can stop searching as soon as you find an id that is greater than the one you are looking for.

Now that you've done that, your insert method is a bit simpler:

1. Get a new node from the user
2. Check if it exists - if so delete the node you just created and give error
3. If not, search the list and find where to insert your new node.

Comment: Bought and read the textbook today and it is nearly identical to this. I should have done that a week ago and have had this problem. Got rid of almost all of the `new` and it works now I changed too much to list. Thank you